# How to use a data binding function of Knockoutjs inside JSON?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

In the following code of Knockoutjs both the first name and last name works. The problem comes with displaying the full name. Its not getting the value of "this.firstName" and "this.lastName". How can i fix this problem.

```js
var AppViewModel = {
    firstName:ko.observable("Bert"), 
    lastName:ko.observable("Bertington"), 
    fullName:ko.pureComputed(function(){
        return this.firstName()+ " "+this.lastName();   
    }, this, {deferEvaluation : false})
};
```

```html
<h1>Introduction</h1>
<p>First name: <strong data-bind="text:firstName">todo</strong></p>
<p>Last name: <strong data-bind="text:lastName">todo</strong></p>

<p>First name: <input data-bind="value:firstName" /></p>
<p>Last name: <input data-bind="value:lastName" /></p>

<p>Full name: <strong data-bind="text:fullName"></strong></p>
```

Comment: use console.dir(this) to debug "this" and to check whether the computed is called at all

Comment: You might need understand more about [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Answer (score 1):

i made some slightly changes as i am used to use knockout

```
var AppViewModel = function (data){
    this.firstName=ko.observable("Bert"), 
    this.lastName=ko.observable("Bertington"), 
    this.fullName=ko.computed(function(){
       return this.firstName() + this.lastName()
    }, this, {deferEvaluation : false})
}

appModel = new AppViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(appModel);
```

here is a working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/su3sfdff/

if you wanted the computed to be "live"

adjust the valueUpdate property this:

```
<p>First name: <input data-bind="value:firstName,valueUpdate:['afterkeydown', 'input']" /></p>
<p>Last name: <input data-bind="value:lastName,valueUpdate:['afterkeydown', 'input']" /></p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/su3sfdff/1/

Comment: Thank you for replying to my question. but i was thinking if it would be possible to make it with JSON as i have written it for the purpose of expanding the object using jquery function called extend later on.